# How can I parse_date_time with letters and timezones?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a pretty standard looking date time as a character. I'm trouble parsing it into the datetime because of the letters and redundancies.

How can I parse this as a datetime?

```
lubridate::parse_date_time("Fri Feb 05 09:58:38 PST 2021", )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify all the formats by directly referring to the documentation of the function `parse_date_time()`. You can find it [here](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_date_time.html). The tricky thing here is that you need to specify the time zone via the argument `tz` and not directly in the argument `orders`.

Below is the code.

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
newdate = parse_date_time("Fri Feb 05 09:58:38 PST 2021", 
                          "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", 
                          tz = "America/Los_Angeles" )
newdate
#> [1] "2021-02-05 09:58:38 PST"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Does this work for you?